# Custom Region doesnt render at the same position

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I have created a region in my theme that contains only menus. Each menu has its own visibility settings. For e.g. my main-menu is everywhere visible except at /blog/* and my blog-menu only at /blog/*. I use this as my main navigation bar region.

My issue is that i call this region in my `page.tpl.php` with

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
<?php //print zurb_foundation_links__topbar_main_menu($main_menu); ?>
    <?php print render($page['menu']);
    ?>
</section>
```

but the html structure that is printed is different to what I need. The following is what gets printed. As you can see its creating a new section with a list inside. I want to get that menu in the section that is currently empty (be aware that I'm printing it at the correct position in my tpl.). I also need to change its ID & CSS Classes.

```
<section class="top-bar-section"></section>
<section class="block block-system contextual-links-region block-menu block-system-main-menu">
        <ul class="menu">
             <li class="first collapsed"><a href="/rubelhp/lernumgebungen">Lernumgebungen</a></li>
             <li class="collapsed"><a href="/rubelhp/unterstuetzung">Unterstützung</a></li>
             <li class="collapsed"><a href="/rubelhp/foerderung">Förderung</a></li>
             <li class="collapsed"><a href="/rubelhp/projekte">Projekte</a></li>
             <li class="last collapsed"><a href="/rubelhp/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>  
</section>
```

I want to avoid to call the menu directly instead of the region. The reason behind it is as I wrote in the beginning the visibility settings. The region contains menus that differ by the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the block template use by your position (block--menu.tpl.php) directly in your theme folder. By default, the render of your menu must use block.tpl.php from the block module.

I recommend you to have a look at the [Working with template suggestions page](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440), and to enable the Theme debug mode to see witch template are used for your block menu.

After, to modify the Classes and the ID of your menu, I recommend you to work with [template_preprocess_block hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x) to modify the block object before the render print it.

You can also have a look at the [theme_menu_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7.x) hook, to be able to modify a wrapper of the menu tree, depending on conditions (menu names).
There is also a THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME possible method, that work only for one specific menu.